# Removing entity and relations from database using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I was trying to find a solution for my problem but luck left me.
To the point.

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "candidates")
    public class Candidate extends AbstractEntityID {
        private String name;
    
        private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    
        private String contactNumber;
    
        private String email;
    
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinTable(name = "possess", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "skill_id")})
        private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Skill> getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void addSkills(Skill skill) {
      skills.add(skill);
      skill.getCandidates().add(this);
    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "skill")
public class Skill extends AbstractEntityID {
    private String skillName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "skills",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Candidate> candidates = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Candidate> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }

    public void setCandidates(Set<Candidate> candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }
```

Get/Set and constructors are omitted for simplicity.
One table candidates contains simple data for candidate, and table skill is table where programming skill are stored. Join table have links which represent that candidateA (with id=1) have skills: java (id=1), C++(id=2) and so on. Join table is populated: (1,1), (1,2)-> candidateA have java and C++ skills.
Now I want to remove candidateA from candidate table. Fist I must remove connections to skills and then remove it.
Nice tutorial found here: [JPA and Hibernate Relations](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3387643/java-persistence-with-jpa-and-hibernate-part-2-many-to-many-relationships.html).
In my service I do this:

```
@Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
//        find candidate
        Candidate candidate = candidateRepository.getOne(id);
//      remove connections
        candidate.getSkills().forEach(skill ->  candidate.getSkills().remove(skill));
//      remove candidate
        candidateRepository.deleteById(id);

    }
```

Candidate repository is defined as:

```
public interface CandidateRepository extends JpaRepository<Candidate, Long>
```

RestController call:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "This option deletes candidate from database")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteCandidate(@PathVariable Long id){
        candidateService.delete(id);

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

When I run my app and try to delete candidate got:

```
"status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "trace": "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1493)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1516)\r\n\tat
```

I found that I'm deleting while iterating so I got this error. In article I mentioned, there is no such error.
Can someone tell me where/what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to empty the set, you can make it = new HashSet<>();
If you want to delete each Skill, you can get a copy of the Set, Empty the Candidate skills, and after, you can delete each skill in the copy.

Comment: I have tried that. It deletes joining table, but do not delete Candidate from candidates table. Any suggestion?